# Formtastic polymorphic form with interchangeable model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, haml, formtastic

So I'm having a problem implementing a form for a model with a polymorphic association. The problem is, I need to offer the choice between two different models to choose from. I'm using HAML and Formtastic. In case anyone is wondering about the models, it's about firewall access list rules.

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ipable_from, foreign_key: 'ipable_from_id', polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :ipable_to, foreign_key: 'ipable_to_id', polymorphic: true
end

class Ip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rules_from, class_name: "Rule", foreign_key: 'ipable_from_id', as: :ipable_from
  has_many :rules_to, class_name: "Rule", foreign_key: 'ipable_to_id', as: :ipable_to
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ip_groups
end

class IpGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rules_from, class_name: "Rule", foreign_key: 'ipable_from_id', as: :ipable_from
  has_many :rules_to, class_name: "Rule", foreign_key: 'ipable_to_id', as: :ipable_to
  has_and_belongs_to_many :ips
end



= semantic_form_for @rule do |f|
  -#...
  = f.semantic_fields_for :ipable_from do |ipf|
    = ipf.input :ip_string, as: :string
    = ipf.input :name, as: :select, collection: @ip_groups
  -#...
```

The same input fields exists for `:ipable_to`. I want it to be processed like this: If the Select-Box for an `IpGroup` is left blank, the `ip_string` is processed, yielding an `Ip`, otherwise, the `ipable` references the chosen `IpGroup`. However, when evaluating the form, Formtastic automatically assumes the current model of the objects `ipable_from` and `ipable_to`, so when `ipable_from` is currently an `Ip`, it tells me, that the attribute `name` could not be found for `Ip`. That is because it's an attribute of `IpGroup`. Is there a way of telling Formtastic to build the form as follows:

```
= semantic_form_for @rule do |f|
  -#...
  = f.semantic_fields_for :ipable_from, as: :ip do |ipf|
    = ipf.input :ip_string, as: :string
  = f.semantic_fields_for :ipable_from, as: :ip_group do |ipf|
    = ipf.input :name, as: :select, collection: @ip_groups
  -#...
```

Like, if `ipable_from` is an `Ip`, display the `ip_string` and leave `id` untouched. If `ipable_from` is an `IpGroup`, the `ip_string` is left blank and the `id` of `IpGroup` is selected in the Select-Box.